# Clip Basemap Layer in QGIS or set a limitation of extens

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, basemap

I have put an OpenStreetMap layer in QGIS and I don't want to zoom or to pan to all the countries there, but I want to focus just in one place.

Is there any possibility to clip the Basemap, or to add some coordinates to limit the view in Qgis?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/153317/87346

Comment: You can use the bookmarks feature to create a zoom extent "bookmark" that you can easily return to. Or create a polygon of the extent you want to zoom to, then right-click on that layer and choose "zoom to layer extent."

Comment: I know these two options you suggested to me, but I want something more efficient for my project. 

I have put OpenStreetMap service and I want to limit the area of zooming in and out. I want to let users to be focused just in one city and I don't want to permit them to pan all over the world (in the basemap :S