# Min and max zoom levels/scales for a QGIS project

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, scale, zoom

We've built a qgis project for use in education and we want to set up a min. and max. zoom level (or scale) for the whole project.

In the project properties, we can specify some "project predefined scales", but this does not prevent from zooming over of these limits.

On each layer, we can set a min/max scale for rendering the layer (in Layer Properties > Rendering), but again, this only hides the layer when zooming over of these limits.

Is this feature available? Can we make it using some pyQGIS chunks of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this solution

```py
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

# Disable mousewheel if you want
# QSettings().setValue("/qgis/zoom_factor", 1)

minScale = 10000000
maxScale = 90000000

def renderStart():
    scale = canvas.scale()
    if scale < minScale:
        canvas.zoomScale(minScale)
    if scale > maxScale:
        canvas.zoomScale(maxScale)
    if scale < minScale or scale > maxScale:
        iface.actionPan().trigger() # Disable zoom in favor of pan

canvas.renderStarting.connect(renderStart)

# canvas.renderStarting.disconnect(renderStart)
```

Comment: Nice thanks! The behaviour is not perfect since it still zoom in/out outside the limits and then quickly zoom at the min/maxScale, but that's better than nothing.

Comment: Yes, only cared about zoom here. You may look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153316/how-to-restrict-panning-in-qgis-to-a-given-extent and do some adaptation to achieve what you want (not only zoom/scale restriction but also extent restriction it seems)